# jQuery row.find finding all controls but dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of a drag and drop option for the table being used for clients, I'm attempting to re-name the controls in each row when the client changes their order.The script works as intended for every control **except** for attempting to find the drop down as shown by [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/deu4enb7/6/). I'm not sure what the problem is, but below is the UpdateNames() script that handles renaming controls and re-coloring rows.

---

```
function UpdateNames() {
    $('.sorted_table tr').each(function (i, row) {

        // Reference all the stuff you need first
        var $row = $(row),
            $remove = $row.find('input[name*="chkRemove_"]'),
            $list = $row.find('input[name*="dlList_"]'),
            $section = $row.find('input[name*="txtSection_"]'),
            $name = $row.find('input[name*="txtName_"]'),
            $value = $row.find('input[name*="txtValue_"]'),
            $comments = $row.find('input[name*="txtComments_"]');

        //Now to actually rename them
        $remove.attr('name', "chkRemove_" + (i - 1));
        $list.attr('name', "dlList_" + (i - 1));
        $section.attr('name', "txtSection_" + (i - 1));
        $name.attr('name', "txtName_" + (i - 1));
        $value.attr('name', "txtValue_" + (i - 1));
        $comments.attr('name', "txtComments_" + (i - 1));

        var rowCSS = 'tableinfobody tableinfoGray';
        if ((i % 2) === 0) {
            rowCSS = 'tableinfobody';
        }
        $row.attr("class", rowCSS);
    });
```

---

I should note that the row coloring also works.

Comment: It's because `<select>` is not an "input". It's a "select".

Comment: Son of a...I'm not sure if sloppy copy/paste rows is to blame, or coding tunnel vision. Make the answer, you'll get credit @Juhana.